# PHP if statement with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and the advanced custom fields plugin to create gallery thumbnails. There are 9 possible upload fields, but only the first is required.

At present I am having an issue where any of the fields are empty it is still outputting the `img` tag but showing a corrupt image (as there is no image).

I need to create an `if` statement that only outputs the HTML if the field has a `src` (or if the field isn't empty).

This is my current code, there are 9 of these:

```
<li>
    <div class="portfolioPicker">
       <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('portfolio_image_2'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
       <img id="portfolioImg_2" class="portfolioPickerThumb" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('portfolio_image_2')) ?>" />
    </div>
</li>
```

I have found a good piece of code for the PHP if statement but am struggling to get it working with my current output code:

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "mycustomfieldname", true) ): ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "mycustomfieldname", $single = true);?>
<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three possible solutions to only display the tag if the array key is set:

```
<li>
    <div class="portfolioPicker">
    <?php
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('portfolio_image_2'), 'thumbnail');
            if($image[0] != NULL)
            {
    ?>
                <img id="portfolioImg_2" class="portfolioPickerThumb" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('portfolio_image_2')) ?>" />
    <?php
            }
    ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

OR

```
<li>
    <div class="portfolioPicker">
    <?php
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('portfolio_image_2'), 'thumbnail');
            if(is_null($image[0]) == false)
            {
    ?>
                <img id="portfolioImg_2" class="portfolioPickerThumb" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('portfolio_image_2')) ?>" />
    <?php
            }
    ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

OR

```
<li>
    <div class="portfolioPicker">
    <?php
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('portfolio_image_2'), 'thumbnail');
            if(empty($image[0]) == false)
            {
    ?>
                <img id="portfolioImg_2" class="portfolioPickerThumb" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('portfolio_image_2')) ?>" />
    <?php
            }
    ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Which function you use and how you use it will depend on the *empty* value itself - what IS "empty"? i.e.
`''`, `0`, `' '`, `NULL`
could all mean empty.

Hope this helps.